# How to add spaces around a certain character in a javascript string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a javascript string:

`var str = 'param 1 | param 2 | someval 1: param 3 | someval 2: param 4';`

I am displaying it on a webpage.

How to make it look like:

```
param 1     |     param 2     |     someval 1: param 3     |    someval 1: param 3
```

Putting `&nbsp;` in between just prints out those `&nbsp;`s.

Comment: Break it up, wrap in spans, use CSS?

Comment: Well if it prints out &nbsp than you are setting text, not html.

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how it slipped my mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't setting the HTML, and that's why the `nbsp` fails:

```js
var str = 'param1 | param2 | &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;param3 | param4';
document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id='a'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just want to add 5 spaces followed by | followed by 5 spaces in between every item. You could just do:

```
str.split(' | ').join('     |     ')
```

Comment: When I'm printing out, it's just ignoring the spaces and prints out one space only.

Comment: @WhatsInAName that's the behavior of HTML. Why don't you wrap those things in a `<pre>` (code) tag? Or you could just replace the whitespace characters with the nbsp ones in the code above.

Comment: Thanks! That was it. I was binding it (using knockout js) to text instead of html but for some reason, only adding &nbsp;s manually before and after each | character works. Tried replacing and splitting without luck.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for but with css you can do it using `word-spacing` property

```css
div {
  word-spacing: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  param1 | param2 | param3 | param4
</div>
```

Comment: This could work but I have stuff like param 1 with a pace in between (will edit the question). This solution will add space there too which is undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to add characters at specific places like this.

And a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to target the `|`.

```js
var str = 'param 1 | param 2 | someval 1: param 3 | someval 2: param 4';

str = str.replace(/\s\|\s/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit** you can use display `flex` and [`replace(string,newstring)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

**previous answer for records** *you can use `word-spacing` or `text-align-last`, not too sure about what visual you are after.*

Demo below , `replace()` at first.

```js
var str = 'param 1 | param 2 | someval 1: param 3 | someval 2: param 4';
document.getElementById('mystring').innerHTML = str;
document.getElementById('juststring').innerHTML = str;
// update & what matters
var newstr = str.replace(/[|]/gi, '<b> $& </b>');
document.getElementById('flexystring').innerHTML = newstr;
```

```css
/* what matters i believe */

#flexystring {
  display: flex;
}

b {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
}
/* what did not really matter */
#mystring {
  word-spacing: 4em;
}

#juststring {
  text-align-last: justify;
}

code,
strong {
  display: block;
}

p+code {
  background: yellow;
}

strong~p+code {
  background: gray;
  color: lightgray;
}
strong {
color:red;
}
p,
strong {
  margin-top: 2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>flex and margin to justify bits of strings</p>
<code id="flexystring"></code>
<strong>irrelevant previous answer left for records </strong>
<p>increase spacing ?</p>
<code id="mystring"></code>
<p>justify string ?</p>
<code id="juststring"></code>
```